# How to push data into state array in react native

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, sorting

Suppose I have an array of ids that reflects my images `[aaa, bbb, ccc]`and I will be using that data to get my images.

I want to use these ids and get my images and store them in an array state which would be used to display my images in flatlist.

My code is as follows.

```
 getIDs() {
        fetch(config)
            .then((response) => {
                 return response.json(); 
            })
            .then(async (data) => {
                data.map(async id => {
                    await this.setImages(id.id)
                }                    );})        }

    async setImages(imageID) {
        await fetch(config ) //where image Id is used
            .then((response) => {
                   return response.json(); 
                                 }                })
            .then(async (data) => {
 await this.setState({ images: this.state.images.concat(data.content), isLoading: false }   
            })
```

The problem with this setState is that it changes the sequence of my images. I want to load my images in a specific sequence that I am getting from my database.

My Flatlist is as follows

```
                    <FlatList
                    data={[...this.state.images]}
                    numColumns={3}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                        return (
                           <Image source={{ uri: 'data:image/png;base64,' + item }} />
                        );
                    }}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setState there for each image, first make an array to contain images and push image there so that theres no change in order and while retrieving do that like you used to do

```
let imagesArray=[];

getIDs() {


        fetch(config)
            .then((response) => {
                 return response.json(); 
            })
            .then(async (data) => {
                data.map(async id => {
                    await this.setImages(id.id)
                }                    ); 
              }
              this.setState({imagesArray:imagesArray})
              )        }

    async setImages(imageID) {
        await fetch(config ) //where image Id is used
            .then((response) => {
                   return response.json(); 
                                 }                })
            .then(async (data) => {
//  await this.setState({ images: this.state.images.concat(data.content), isLoading: false } 
imagesArray.push (data.content) 
            }) :,
```

hope it helps

Comment: I didn't get where to declare imagesArray? Thanks for help

Comment: if you are using inside a class then you can decalre a variable at top and use it, just tht it should be accessible to both flatlist and setItem

Comment: No mate The problem still continues.